# Bind to Model or ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I created a project using MVVM pattern (or so I thought ;) ). To simplify my case:

**Model**:

```
public class Model {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefective { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel** - extends MvvmLight `ViewModelBase`:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    private ObservableCollection<Model> models;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Models {
        get {
            if (_models== null) {
                _models= new ObservableCollection<Models>();
            }

            return _models;
        }
        set {
            RaisePropertyChanged("Models");

            _models= value;
        }
    }
}
```

**View** - I'm showing a list of textboxes:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=.IsDefective}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

My scenario is like so: some methods in the `Model` class may change the IsDefective property, but since my model does not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, my view does not know about such changes. How should this problem be resolved "the mvvm way"? I stumbled upon this question here in SO, but to be honest after reading both highest voted answers and the discussion in comments, I'm more confused: [MVVM - PropertyChanged in Model or ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864610/mvvm-propertychanged-in-model-or-viewmodel) . I'm willing to agree with Jonathan Allen, because it's just more natural for me to bind this way, but as a beginner in the mvvm pattern I may be missing something. So, am I?

Comment: Your not missing any thing , Mvvm and it's counter parts are a  suggestion , it helps you create maintainable , testable and decoupled pieces of code. 
it is perfectly legitimate for your model to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

It's very popular in 'CRUD' applications.

Comment: _"...some methods in the Model class may change the IsDefective property..."_
Could you please clarify **which class** calls the method of Model (the method that may change the `IsDefective` property)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally you want your model to be a dumb data transfer object. When you do a database query, you get a dumb model back that doesn't do any transformations because otherwise you're failing to follow Separation of Concerns in SOLID principals. However, cheating a little won't kill you, but it might make debugging something a little frustrating because most people won't expect their POCO (plain old CLR object) to initiate any business logic.

Here's some code:

Some setup classes:

## ViewModelBase.cs

A "smarter" version of the ViewModelBase from galasoft, this bad boy autowires up design time view models (you'll like this one)

```
namespace WPFPlayground.ViewModel
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void SetValue<T>(ref T property, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (property != null)
            {
                if (property.Equals(value)) return;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            property = value;
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

### DefectiveToBackgroundColorConverter.cs

A value converter for our use when our product is being displayed on the view (you'll see it referenced later):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WPFPlayground
{
    public class DefectiveToBackgroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value))
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }
}
```

Using Model-first method:

## ProductModel.cs

POCO DTO

```
namespace WPFPlayground.Model
{
    public class ProductModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefective { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## ProductViewModel.cs

Notice the use of setvalue to automatically wire up the notifypropertychanged event.

```
namespace WPFPlayground.ViewModel
{
    public class ProductViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _name;
        private bool _isDefective;

        public bool IsDefective
        {
            get { return _isDefective; }
            set { SetValue(ref _isDefective, value); }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { SetValue(ref _name, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

So we have a productmodel and a productviewmodel. One does all the work when you're interacting with the database, and one does all the work when you bind to your views.

So we'll need a view that represents just a single productviewmodel:

## ProductView.xaml

Notice the use of the background color converter to handle our triggers

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFPlayground.View.ProductView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:wpfPlayground="clr-namespace:WPFPlayground"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance wpfPlayground:DesignProductViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <wpfPlayground:DefectiveToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="DefectiveToBackgroundColorConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Viewbox>
        <Border Width="500" Background="{Binding IsDefective, Converter={StaticResource DefectiveToBackgroundColorConverter}}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="40" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Next we'll need that design time viewmodel so we can view our XAML in design time:

## DesignProductViewModel.cs

A bit boring, but it makes design time work!

```
using WPFPlayground.ViewModel;

namespace WPFPlayground
{
    public class DesignProductViewModel : ProductViewModel
    {
        public DesignProductViewModel()
        {
            Name = "This is my product";
            IsDefective = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we need to display a list of these viewmodels:

### MainWindow.xaml

Itemscontrol all day err day

```
<Window x:Class="WPFPlayground.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WPFPlayground.ViewModel"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WPFPlayground.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModel:DesignProductsViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ProductViewModel}">
            <view:ProductView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
            <view:ProductView />
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

## DesignProductsViewModel.cs

The design time view model so you can see this working in design time. It generates an easy random set of products.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace WPFPlayground.ViewModel
{
    public class DesignProductsViewModel : ProductsViewModel
    {
        public DesignProductsViewModel()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            Products = new ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new ProductViewModel
            {
                Name = String.Format(@"Product {0}", i),
                IsDefective = (random.Next(1, 100) < 50)
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that your DTO's can stay 'DUMB' you can create a wrapper for the UI side for your Dto's where it implement's INotifyPropertyChanged 
but most of the time it's just redundant and inconvenient ..

Comment: Words like redundant and inconvenient are things people use to dismiss TDD, SOLID principals, and other beneficiary practices. Just because it's inconveniant, doesn't mean it should be discarded.

Comment: So in your opinion - in this particular scenario - should I create an additional layer for my view to model binding, or should I cheat? I've written some test cases and it was easy - I had no trouble with this code, but maybe the additional layer would make writing tests even more easy (once again - in this particular case)?

Comment: In other words - what benefits would I get in this case if I'd not be exposing model directly to the view? It's a simple example, but my application will grow.

Comment: It's completely up to you my friend. In my applications, there would have been a "Model"ViewModel and I would have done my notifypropertychanged attributes there. That is the purpose of MVVM. If you add this little smidge of business logic to your model, what happens if a new business requirement turns up? You add it there too, I guess. Eventually the model, expecting to be a DTO, is doing a bunch of business logic when it's just supposed to be a DTO. In small projects it probably won't burn you.

Comment: So in this case - could you possibly give me an example code I could work on?

Comment: OKAY! I put something up for you friend. If you want I'll post it to github where it might be easier to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Your not missing any thing , Mvvm and it's counter parts are suggestions which help you create maintainable , testable and decoupled pieces of code.

When you come across a situation  where you duplicate code just to satisfy Mvvm you can "cheat".

It is perfectly legitimate for your model to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
It's very popular in 'CRUD' applications.