# Binding Model to ViewModel (WPF)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, prism, ioc-container

I'm making the move from MVP to MVVM, and a little confused as to how best bind the `ViewModel` to the `Model`. I understand how we can leverage WPF's data binding infrastructure to route events between the `View` and `ViewModel` using `ICommand` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, e.g., the `View`:

```cs
public class MyView
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

and the `ViewModel`:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyViewModel(){}

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand ... 
}
```

This works great!

Now, typically with MVP I'd have my `Presenter` hold a reference to the `Model` via constructor injection, and raise events on the `Model` from the `Presenter` to update data in the `Model`. I tried the same approach with MVVM, but this requires the `ViewModel` to take the `Model` as a dependency in its constructor, which seems to make things a little messy with MVVM when using it straight out of the box without some form of IOC (with WPF at least).

So, my two questions are:

1. Is injecting the `Model` into the `ViewModel` the right approach, or should I be implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the `Model` and making use of WPF's binding infrastructure?
2. To reap the benefits of MVVM, should you almost always implement it with IOC and a DI container, or better still Prism?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947122/binding-to-model-or-viewmodel.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864610/mvvm-propertychanged-in-model-or-viewmodel

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772214/in-mvvm-should-the-viewmodel-or-model-implement-inotifypropertychanged

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421874/basic-concepts-of-mvvm-what-should-a-viewmodel-do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It is the "pure" MVVM approach: the `View` must depend only on the `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` itself is a bridge between the `View` and `Model`.

   The motivation — definition and responsibilities of the `Model`, `View` and  `ViewModel` and also their relationships:

   > - The Model, which provides a **view-independent representation** of your business entities. The design of the model is optimized for the logical relationships and operations between your business entities, regardless of how the data is presented in the user interface.
   > - The View class which is the **user interface**. It displays information to the user and fires events in response to user interactions.
   > - The ViewModel class, which is **the bridge between the view and the model**. Each View class has a corresponding ViewModel class. The ViewModel retrieves data **from the Model and manipulates it into the format required by the View**. It notifies the View if the underlying data in the model is changed, and it updates the data in the Model in response to UI events from the View.
   >
   > -- [Implementing the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern, MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx).

   Conclusion. Injecting the `Model` into the `ViewModel` seems to be the right approach. Also, instead of injecting `Model` it can be useful to inject:

   - the `Model Factory` to create the `Model` — lazy initialization;
   - the `Service` (`Service Facade`) to retrieve the `Model` — lazy loading.
2. As shown in the ["MVVM Unleashed" book by Michael Brown](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672334380), the following MVVM's potential benefits can be leveraged: maintainability, testability, "blendability", portability. At least, dependency injection (in the described case by using dependency injection container) allows a design to follow the Dependency Inversion Principle:

   > The principle of dependency inversion is at the root of many of the benefits claimed for object-oriented technology. Its proper application is necessary for the creation of reusable frameworks. It is also critically important for the construction of code that is resilient to change. And, since the abstractions and details are all isolated from each other, the code is much easier to maintain.
   >
   > -- [The Dependency Inversion Principle, Robert C. Martin, 1996](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf).

   As a result, such MVVM's benefits as the maintainability and testability seem to be improved when the Dependency Inversion Principle is followed. Dependency injection container is just a tool to follow the Principle.