# Why should I use Independent<double>

Tags: wpf, user-controls

In the user control(this is not my code), I have found part of code that I don't understand why to use Independent and not a dependency property.
Can someone please explain.Thanks

```
 <Label Content="{Binding Flow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:N1}" />
```

ViewModel

```
 private Independent<double> _flow = new Independent<double>(10.567);
    public double Flow
    {
        get { return _flow; }
        private set { _flow.Value = value; }
    }
```

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a one-way binding is pointless. It has no effect, because the binding never updates the source. Besides that, what is `Independant`?

Comment: Yes, what is Independent?

Comment: You should tell us that. It's not part of WPF.

Comment: Now there is an accepted answer, but we still don't know what `Independent<T>` is. How should this be of any use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, usually dependency properties are in custom controls' code behind, not in view models. And usually you want your properties in a view model to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There is no OnPropertyChanged or similar call in this property setter, so it's probably what the setter of the `Value` property in `Independent<double>` does.

I guess `Independent<T>` is a wrapper class that raises OnPropertyChanged and does some other stuff, like a `viewmodel property base` class. Look at the [ValueViewModel](https://gist.github.com/sbrunov/6535186) class mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324009/mvvm-modified-model-how-to-correctly-update-viewmodel-and-view) as an example.